# Tracking releases, branches or tags?

Tags: git, release, development-environment

How do you keep track of your releases?

Currently, we have 2 main branches

- dev
- release

Ongoing development done by several people always happens in `dev`. Once sufficient amount of changes are done, code is merged into `release`, built from it and tagged in it. Then the code is deployed.

**The problem:** This works fine, but often, new bugs come into play which are currently dealt with in a dev branch, that has .. moved on (sometimes by a lot). Once issue is fixed, that new build that comes out to the customers often contains both the fix and some new functionality.

I'd like to change the process to the following:

- current   <- current dev stream, latest and greatest, **not yet deployed**
- prod      <- currently in prod, merged from dev/1.0.2
- dev/1.0.0 <- built and delivered to prod some time ago
- dev/1.0.1 <- bug fix to previous build, to be built and delivered to prod
- dev/1.0.2 <- bug fix to previous build, to be built and delivered to prod. **currently in prod**

What do you think? Is this trend going to work and be sustainable long term? We do release about 15 times per year each release having at least 2-3 post prod accidents that need to be fixed, so roughly, we'll have 75 branches per year (which is a lot, but i suppose after a while they can be removed)

Comment: You want to fix bugs on your `release` branch and be able to deploy them to production without bringing in work in progress from the `dev` branch? Can't you just branch directly from `release`, fix the bug, and merge that branch's changes both in `release` and in `dev`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If several people work on the new features (and improvements of existing features) and they all use the dev branch to commit their code, you can never be sure that the dev branch is stable. If the developers use feature branches to build new features and only merge those into the dev branch when a feature is completed, the dev branch always should be stable. (Then the feature branch can be deleted too.)

I like the solution of [`git flow`](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). You have a master (production) branch and a development branch. Also there are feature branches where you can work on new features and hotfix branches for things that need to be fixed on production and can't wait till the next release.